# Including project reference for WiX installer

Tags: windows, installation, wix, dependencies

Coming from a VS Setup project, where it automatically adds the dependencies within each project into the resulting msi, is there a way to do that in WiX as well?

For example project A references b.dll which exists in the GAC. It seems that b.dll is not being added to the resulting msi and it then crashes when the application is ran. Do I have to manually add b.dll as a component in the .wxs file or can it be done automatically like the VS setup project?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this link [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg39922.html), I've concluded that it's currently not possible to do it automatically in version 3.5